# Can anybody please explain AFHTTPSessionManager

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

Can anyone please explain what is happening in the following code:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager GET:[url absoluteString]
  parameters:nil
     success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id JSON) {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", JSON);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is too broad for this site. Please read this before posting any more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: There are too many restrictions on asking questions for beginners here. Its really annoying.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But on the other hand you have to understand, that to keep this answer base and SO search engine useful in any way, there has to be a strict level of acceptance. A question like yours is easily searchable using standard web search engines and does not provide any value here. Beginners should focus on tutorials, books and documentation. SO is for solving specific, preferably non-trivial programming problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
```

This is simply an instance of the class which manages `HTTP`connections.

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

This means that any parameters of your request (in your case there are no parameters, but usually a dictionary is passed there) will be sent over the network as `JSON`.

```
[manager GET:[url absoluteString]
 parameters:nil
 success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id JSON) {
     NSLog(@"JSON: %@", JSON);
}
```

Here the manager performs `GET` request to the specified url without any parameters and receives some `JSON` data in the response block. You can turn this `JSON` into a dictionary or array and use according to your needs.